# How many arrangments of the word PROBABILISTIC have no two I's appearing consecutively?

Tags: combinatorics

What I did: Using stars-and-bars, I arranged the **I**'s in the $13$ given spots in ${11\choose 3}$ ways, and then arranged the remaining $10$ letters in $10!$ ways. Dividing the $10!$ by $2$ to avoid unwanted overlapping between the two $B$'s, we should get our final answer as $\frac{10!}{2}\cdot {11\choose 3}$.

Is this the right approach? And could someone verify this answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't there $13$ letters in probabilistic?  But the approach is fine and it looks like the numbers are right too, though I don't understand what you mean by "$14$ given spots".

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while typing it out. Corrected it now.

Comment: No problem.  Aside from the typo, everything looks good.

Comment: A simpler way is to find the total number of ways minus the number of ways that do not satisfy the conditions (i.e. $2$ 'I's appear consecutively).

Comment: @IraeVid be careful with that approach not to confuse (II)I with I(II) and overcount.  I would sooner do it directly here, especially for problems who have an even greater number of such letters that shouldn't appear together.